# Where does Git persists settings?

Tags: git

I'm on Windows 7 and trying to completely format Git, but re-installing it I notice the previous settings persist.
How can I completely delete Git and start fresh?
Where does it store these files?

Comment: "format git": these words don't exist together.

Comment: to see where a config parameter comes from, you can run : `git config --show-origin <config.param>`. To see this for *all* of your config parameters : `git config --list --show-origin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*~ /.gitconfig* on unix systems and *C:\Users\.gitconfig* on windows